# Как запретить индексацию всех страниц с определенным get-параметром в robots.txt?

Tags: оптимизация, seo, индексация, robots.txt

Яндекс пожаловался на то, что присутствует некоторое кол-во дубликатов страниц с get-параметром.
Ссылка на подобную страницу выглядит примерно так: `site.ru/blog/article?layout=new`
Параметр всегда одинаков, но его значение меняется. Как запретить индексацию всех ссылок с layout=""? Насколько правильным будет `Disallow: *?*layout=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта конструкция абсолютно верная:

```
Disallow: *?*layout=
```

Однако надо учитывать, что она запретит индексацию всех страниц, которые содержат параметр `layout`, независимо от его положения в списке параметров и наличия других параметров в адресе. Т.е. все указанные ниже примеры страниц не будут индексироваться:

```
site.ru/blog/article?layout=new
site.ru/blog/article?layout=old
site.ru/blog/article?layout=old&author=Example
site.ru/blog/article?page=1&layout=fashion
site.ru/blog/article?page=2&layout=new&author=Example
```

Comment: не совсем так. Это избыточная конструкция. Да, она запретит индексацию искомого параметра, но также будет запрещена индексация site.ru/blog/article?param-layout=new

Answer (score 0):

Я делаю это через Clean-param: в robots.txt по двум причинам:

1. Снижается нагрузка на сервер обхода.
2. Если закрывать от индекса с помощью Disallow или тега noindex, тогда поисковики так же не будут индексировать и учитывать обратные ссылки на такие страницы. А если закрывать от индекса этим методом, тогда беклинки учтутся сайту.

**Эти плюсы относятся только к Yandex!**

А в Google получите ошибку в robots.txt, что-то не совмещаются в этом моменте. Но я ее игнорирую и всё нормально.

Для гугла, с моей точки зрения решать проблему таких дублей с помощью [этого чудесного инструмента,](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-url-parameters) почитайте, поймете все плюсы. А если не поймете, то лучше не трогайте!