# Как избавиться от страниц-дублей с разными GET-параметрами

Tags: seo, robots.txt, яндекс-поиск

Сегодня яндекс прислал:

> Здравствуйте!
>
> На вашем сайте [https://сайт.ru](https://xn--80aswg.ru) некоторые страницы с GET-параметрами в
> URL дублируют содержимое других страниц (без GET-параметров).
> Например, https://example.com/tovary?from=mainpage дублирует
> https://example.com/tovary. Из-за их обхода информация о важных для
> вас страницах может медленнее передаваться в поисковую базу, что может
> влиять на состояние сайта в поиске.
>
> Вот примеры страниц и дублирующих их страниц с незначащими
> GET-параметрами:
>
> SHOWALL_1:
> [https://сайт.ru/catalog/aerobika_i_aksessuary/](https://xn--80aswg.ru/catalog/aerobika_i_aksessuary/)
> [https://сайт.ru/catalog/aerobika_i_aksessuary/?SHOWALL_1=1](https://xn--80aswg.ru/catalog/aerobika_i_aksessuary/?SHOWALL_1=1)
>
> SHOWALL_1:
> [https://сайт.ru/catalog/edinoborstva/](https://xn--80aswg.ru/catalog/edinoborstva/)
> [https://сайт.ru/catalog/edinoborstva/?SHOWALL_1=1](https://xn--80aswg.ru/catalog/edinoborstva/?SHOWALL_1=1)
>
> SHOWALL_1:
> [https://сайт.ru/catalog/napolnye_pokrytiya/?sort=cheap](https://xn--80aswg.ru/catalog/napolnye_pokrytiya/?sort=cheap)
> [https://сайт.ru/catalog/napolnye_pokrytiya/?sort=cheap&SHOWALL_1=1](https://xn--80aswg.ru/catalog/napolnye_pokrytiya/?sort=cheap&SHOWALL_1=1)
>
> order:
> [https://сайт.ru/catalog/roboty_dlya_nastolnogo_tennisa/?sort=expensive](https://xn--80aswg.ru/catalog/roboty_dlya_nastolnogo_tennisa/?sort=expensive)
> [https://сайт.ru/catalog/roboty_dlya_nastolnogo_tennisa/?sort=expensive&order=](https://xn--80aswg.ru/catalog/roboty_dlya_nastolnogo_tennisa/?sort=expensive&order=)
>
> order: [https://сайт.ru/catalog/velotrenazhery_kettler/?sort=cheap](https://xn--80aswg.ru/catalog/velotrenazhery_kettler/?sort=cheap)
> [https://сайт.ru/catalog/velotrenazhery_kettler/?sort=cheap&order=asc](https://xn--80aswg.ru/catalog/velotrenazhery_kettler/?sort=cheap&order=asc)
>
> Если эти страницы действительно являются дублями, рекомендуем
> использовать директиву Clean-param в robots.txt, чтобы робот
> игнорировал незначащие GET-параметры и объединил все сигналы со
> страниц-копий на основной странице.
>
> Добавьте в файл robots.txt директиву Clean-param, чтобы робот не
> учитывал незначащие GET-параметры в URL. Робот Яндекса, используя эту
> директиву, не будет много раз обходить повторяющийся контент. Значит,
> эффективность обхода повысится, а нагрузка на сайт снизится. Если вы
> не можете добавить директиву Clean-param, укажите

Подскажите, как правильно в robots это сделать через Clean-param? Не понимаю(

Answer (score 0):

[Прочитайте оба ответа здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1309623/), прежде чем принимать решение о способе. Clean-param достаточно хорошо, подробно и с примерами [объясняется в Яндекс](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/robot-workings/clean-param.html).

Или вам нужно как-то пересказать ещё более подробно то, что там уже разжёвано?

Чем отличаются эти два адреса?:

https://.../aerobika_i_aksessuary/

https://.../aerobika_i_aksessuary/**?SHOWALL_1=1**

Ну или этот... с двумя параметрами

https://.../velotrenazhery_kettler/**?sort=cheap&order=asc**

**?SHOWALL_1=1** — GET-параметр запроса страницы, который может быть как необходимой частью URL ведущей к другому контенту, так и простым параметром сортировки содержимого на странице, который поисковики в итоге видят как просто повторяющийся контент и предполагают что это вам не нужно. Именно с этим вам и предстоит разобраться: нужна ли вам индексация этого контента и принять решение.